# If else script in bash using grep and awk

Tags: bash, awk, grep

I am trying to make a script to check if the value snp (column $4 of the test file) is present in another file (map file). If so, print the value snp and the value distance taken from the map file (distance is the column $4 of the map file). If the snp value from the test file is not present in the map file, print the snp value but put a 0 (zero) in the second column as distance value.

The script is:

```
for chr in {1..22}; 
do
for snp in awk '{print $4}' test$chr.bim
i=$(grep $snp map$chr.txt | wc -l | awk '{print $1}')
if [[ $i == "0" ]]
then 
echo "$snp 0" >> position.$chr
else
distance=$(grep $snp map$chr.txt | awk '{print $4}')
echo "$snp $distance" >> position.$chr
fi
done
done
```

my map file is made like this:

```
Chromosome  Position(bp)    Rate(cM/Mb) Map(cM)
chr22   16051347    8.096992    0.000000
chr22   16052618    8.131520    0.010291
chr22   16053624    8.131967    0.018472
```

and so on..

my test file is made like this:

```
22  16051347    0   16051347    C   A
22  16052618    0   16052618    G   T
22  17306184    0   17306184    T   G
```

and so on..

I'm getting the following syntax errors:

```
position.sh: line 6: syntax error near unexpected token `i=$(grep $snp map$chr.txt | wc -l | awk '{print $1}')'
position.sh: line 6: `i=$(grep $snp map$chr.txt | wc -l | awk '{print $1}')'
```

Any tip?

Comment: about `test$chr.bim` does this mean that name of your file is test"something"? If yes, try to rename the file. The word "test" has a special usage for bash.

Comment: Hello. No, my actual file has another name (Roma_test_chr$chr.bim). I wrote test only to make it simpler to explain in here

Comment: Please add a suitable shebang (`#!/bin/bash`) and then paste your script at http://www.shellcheck.net/ and try to implement the recommendations made there.

Comment: Yes, follow the advise of Cyrus. You have quite a lot of synthax errors , i.e missing semicolons `;`

Comment: @GeorgeVasiliou That's not correct either; it will quote the output of Awk and regard it as a single value.

Comment: Please add the expected output given your posted sample input so we have something that demonstrates your problem and we can copy/paste to test with.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The attempt to use `awk` as the argument to `for` is basically a syntax error, and you have a number of syntax problems and inefficiencies here.

Try this:

```
for chr in {1..22}; do
    awk '{print $4}' "test$chr.bim" |
    while IFS="" read -r snp; do
        if ! grep -q "$snp" "map$chr.txt"; then
            echo "$snp 0"
        else
            awk -v snp="$snp" '
                $0 ~ snp { print snp, $4 }' "map$chr.txt"
        fi  >> "position.$chr"
    done
done
```

The entire thing could probably be further refactored to a single Awk script.

```
for chr in {1..22}; do
    awk 'NR == FNR { ++a[$4]; next }
      $2 in a { print a[$2], $4; ++found[$2] }
      END { for(k in a) if (!found[k]) print a[k], 0 }' \
         "test$chr.bim"  "map$chr.txt" >> "position.$chr"
done
```

The correct `for` syntax for what I'm guessing you wanted would look like

```
for snp in $(awk '{print $4}' "test$chr.bim"); do
```

but this has other problems; see [don't read lines with `for`](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/DontReadLinesWithFor)

Comment: @Gf.Ena don't use the first script, use the second (or something similar if it's not totally correct). The first one will be extremely slow and it's just not necessary to keep jumping in/out of awk and other tools. See [why-is-using-a-shell-loop-to-process-text-considered-bad-practice](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/169716/why-is-using-a-shell-loop-to-process-text-considered-bad-practice)

Comment: @EdMorton I've tried the second script but it only prints a column of 1 and a second column of 0, that'it. I'm trying to see what's wrong but so far no success

Comment: That would imply the 4th column of your map file is always 0s.

Comment: If you still need help, probably post a new question with a [mre] where you have a representative input which does not generate the desired output, and you explain how the actual output is different from what you want. (But do search for existing questions; how to perform different joins in Awk is a very common topic.)